# discord py - Как сделать так чтобы после перезапуска кнопки работали

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.slash_command(name = "ter", description = "Лист ", guild=disnake.Object(id=12417128931))
async def dsaa(ctx):
    test = disnake.Embed(title=f"Страница 1")
    test.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
    test.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar.url)  
    await ctx.response.send_message(view = sama(ctx.author), embed=test) 
class sama(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author):
        self.author = author
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
    @disnake.ui.button(label="<--",style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray) # or .primary
    async def blurple_button(self,button:disnake.ui.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        test = disnake.Embed(title=f"Страница 1")
        test.set_author(name=interaction.author.name, icon_url=interaction.author.avatar.url)
        test.set_thumbnail(url=interaction.author.avatar.url)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=test)
        button.disabled=True 
        button.disabled=True
    @disnake.ui.button(label="-->",style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray) # or .success
    async def green_button(ctx,button:disnake.ui.Button,interaction:disnake.Embed):
        test = disnake.Embed(title=f"Страница 2")
        test.set_author(name=interaction.author.name, icon_url=interaction.author.avatar.url)
        test.set_thumbnail(url=interaction.author.avatar.url)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=test, view = sama1(interaction.author))
        button.disabled=True`введите сюда код`
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно настроить постоянство, чтобы бот перезапускал представление вашей кнопки при запуске. Я думаю, вы используете библиотеку разногласий Rapptz? Если да, то вот пример, который вы можете проверить: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py

Comment: нет это disnake и python